# Auto Model Class Generator for Spring Data for Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Does Spring Data for Apache Cassandra have an CLI or any IDE plugin that can auto generate the model classes by connecting to the existing DB and fetching the schema?

Something similar to sequelize-auto (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto) or Hibernate Tools (https://hibernate.org/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

No, actually there isnt a functioniliy like that.